# Cannot find /usr/bin/ in nautilus

Tags: nautilus, command-line, root, startup-applications

I'm trying to get the program "Desktop Drapes" to run on startup, and so far the only guide that's gotten me anywhere is this one: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8810911#post8810911

Things progress smoothly until I enter gksudo nautilus into the terminal. According to the guide, from here I should be able to /usr/bin and change the properties of "drapestart." However, in the root folder I find only a Desktop icon that leads to an empty menu.

I've entered gksudo nautilus while cd'd into /usr/bin and from [username]@[username]-desktop:~$, and the result is the same. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for taking the time out to read this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line with your question.
When you run "gksudo nautilus" it opens  in root's home directory, not yours.

Simply click on "File System"  in nautilus's left sidebar & then navigate wherever, in this case to usr > bin

Or include where you wish to go in the command, like

```
gksudo nautilus /usr/bin
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that'll be good to know in the future. Truly you men are heroes to our republic!

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way would be to open the `Start-Up Application` window and when creating the new entry use the command line:

```
bash -c "sleep 20 && drapes &"
```

i.e. you dont really need to create a file in /usr/bin since the above will achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make a file executable, IMO, is to use the chmod command:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/drapestart
```